# ExitTransition doesn't work if not set up in onCreate

Tags: android, android-activity, android-transitions

I would like to set up my exit transition with specific target views ([addTarget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Transition#addTarget(android.view.View))) which I only know after the user has clicked an item, therefore I instantiate it only before starting the new activity.

However, this way the exit transition is not applied at all, event without the `addTarget` calls. When I navigate back and start the activity with transition again, it's working well.

```
private fun onItemClick(id: Long) {
  window.exitTransition = Slide(Gravity.LEFT)

  val activityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, ..).toBundle()

  val intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
  ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, intent, activityOptions)
}
```

Can I make the transition work also for the first time?

Comment: I created a [sample app](https://github.com/b4rd/exit-transition-test) where this late initialization of the transition works well. I'll try to figure what the problem is in my app.

Comment: Ok cool. Glad you are making progress. It's tough to tell what the problem is from the information provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exit transition must be set before calling `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation` to make it work.

I figured it out by looking at these classes:

[ActivityTransitionCoordinator](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityTransitionCoordinator.java)

[ExitTransitionCoordinator](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ExitTransitionCoordinator.java)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the correct behavior but tough to know without a code example.

The recommended way to change the transitions is

```
// inside your activity (if you did not enable transitions in your theme)
with(window) {
    requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS)

    // set an exit transition
    exitTransition = Explode()
}
```

as discussed here: https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity

---

If you are having this problem in the AndroidStudio emulator specifically, you might want to update AndroidStudio. I had a problem in an older version where a button's behavior was always different the fist time I refreshed the app.

Comment: There is no such thing as exitTransition then you're transitioning between layouts. The question is about activity transitions: https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity.html
I'm going to refine my question nevertheless.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the clarification. I'll edit my answer.